# regular expression capture groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm learning regular expression (currently on Javascript).

My question is that:

I have a straight string of some length.

In this string there are at least (obligatory) three patterns.

And as a result I want to `rule.exec()` string and get a three-elements array. Each pattern into a separate element.

How should I approach this? Currently I have reached it, but with a lot of up and downs and don't know what should EXACTLY be done to group a capture? Is it parenthesis `()` that separate each group of Regular Expression.

My Regular Expression Rule example:

```
var rule = /([a-zA-Z0-9].*\s?(@classs?)+\s+[a-zA-Z0-9][^><]*)/g;
var str = "<Home @class www.tarjom.ir><string2 stringValue2>";
var res;
var keys = [];
var values = [];
while((res = rule.exec(str)) != null)
{
    values.push(res[0]);
}
 console.log(values);

// begin to slice them
var sliced = [];
for(item in values)
{
    sliced.push(values[item].split(" "));// converting each item into an array and the assign them to a super array
}



/// Last Updated on 7th of Esfand
console.log(sliced);
```

And the return result (with firefox 27 - firebug console.log)

```
 [["Home", "@class", "www.tarjom.ir"]]
```

I have got what I needed, I just need a clarification on the return pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [parentheses capture everything between them](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Captured groups are numbered by their opening parenthesis. So if `/(foo)((bar)baz)/` matches, your first captured group will contain `foo`, your second `barbaz`, and your third `bar`. In some dialects, only the first 9 capturing groups are numbered.

Captured groups can be used for [backreferencing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html). If you want to match "foobarfoo", `/(foo)bar\1/` will do that, where `\1` means "the first group I captured".

There are ways to avoid capturing, if you just need the parenthesis for grouping. For instance, if you want to match either "foo" or "foobar", `/(foo(bar)?)/` will do so, but may have captured "bar" in its second group. If you want to avoid this, use `/(foo(?:bar)?)/` to only have one capture, either "foo" or "foobar".

---

The reason [your code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22146322/2936460) shows three values, is because of something else. First, you do a match. Then, you take your first capture and split that on a space. *That* is what you put in your array of results. Note that you push the *entire* array in there at once, so you end up with an array of arrays. Hence the double brackets.

Your regex matches (pretending we're in Perl's eXtended legibility mode):

```
/                   # matching starts
  (                 # open 1st capturing group
    [a-zA-Z0-9]     # match 1 character that's in a-z, A-Z, or 0-9
    .*              # match as much of any character possible
    \s?             # optionally match a white space (this will generally never happen, since the .* before it will have gobbled it up)
    (               # open 2nd capturing group
      @classs?      # match '@class' or '@classs'
    )+              # close 2n group, matching it once or more
    \s+             # match one or more white space characters
    [a-zA-Z0-9]     # match 1 character that's in a-z, A-Z, or 0-9
    [^><]*          # match any number of characters that's not an angle bracket
  )                 # close 1st capturing group
/g                  # modifiers - g: match globally (repeatedly match throughout entire input)
```

Comment: then if I have three sets of parenthesis `()()()` I will get three capture groups?